# SVN/Apache - no request for username and password

Tags: apache, svn, amazon-ec2

I've installed and configured subversion on Amazon ec2 linux instance. Have defined both password and access lists. However when trying to access the repository either from browser or from Tortoise I am not being prompted for username/password. although I am getting a read-only access to it.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Do you have 'require valid-user' in your stanza for this subdirectory?

Comment: It sounds like anonymous access is enabled. I think this can be controlled in either the apache config or svn config.

Comment: @hd1: yes, it is in SVN config

Comment: @datasage: yes, it does. but I can't find anything related to that. Where/what should I check/change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was

```
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
</LimitExcept>
```

uncommented in the config file, which allows anonymous access.